# A line before/left and after/right text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have h3 and would like to have a line before/left and after/right DAY-BY-DAY word, but can only achieve line on the top and at the bottom of that word with ::after and ::before. How can I achieve this with flex, please help.

[image]

Something like ----DAY-BY-DAY----

Here is html:

```
<h3 id ="daybyday"><span style="font-style: italic; font-size: 23px; color: #7B7B7A;">DAY-BY-DAY</span><`/h3>`
```

Here is CSS:

```
#daybyday::before {
             content: "";
             display: block;
             background: salmon;
             height: 5px;
         }

        #daybyday::after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            background: salmon;
            height: 5px;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

So what we do here is, we create a div with `color: salmon` and height of `5px`, then we set the flex property  for the element using `display:flex`, by using flex property (`align-items:center` -> for vertical centering and `justify-content:center` -> for horizontal centering, we can get the `h3` element in the center of the line, finally to prevent the div which is behind the `h3` element from being visible, I set the `background-color:white`, so that it is not visible!

```css
#daybyday {
  display: inline;
  background-color:white;
}

.text-special {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #7B7B7A;
}

.line {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 5px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <h3 id="daybyday"><span class="text-special">DAY-BY-DAY</span></h3>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but no. I want something like this ----DAY-By-DAY----

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian Updated my answer!

Comment: Much appreciated. I will accept this. Do you mind to explain me what is going on here? Please.

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian Thanks, please find my updated answer with the explanation!